# How can I do partial class without using partial keyword?

Tags: c#, .net, class, partial, partial-classes

I was asked in an interview about it. How can I repeat functionality of this keyword? (С# .NET)

EDIT 1: Yeah, I think this is a bad question, but it is interesting to know that would answer you guys

EDIT 2: Thank you everyone for answers, I get the idea!

Comment: You can't. The concept known as "partial class" in C# can only be implemented with the `partial` keyword. Or do what `CommuSoft` said, combine files.

Comment: They couldn't think of better questions?

Comment: perhaps they were speaking of using a base class?  If that is the case it is inferior to using partial.

Comment: Using base classes will not "repeat" the functionality of a partial class. There's things you can do with partial classes that you can only do with partial classes.

Comment: You can't repeat the functionality, but you can do similar things with inheritence and encapsulation.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I know.  I think its a stupid question, but was just taking a stab at what they might be talking about.

Comment: Yes, you can do *similar things*, but if asked how to do *partial classes*, that's not the same. The question as it stands needs clarification (or needed it during the interview) what kind of functionality of partial classes they required for the answer to be accepted. Perhaps *that* was the real answer, "What do you mean, what functionality is it that you need?"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the correct answer(s) to this question can only be provided by the people conducting the interview, everything else will be guesswork.

Comment: the interviewer himself might not have the answer, but ask it anyway, next time, you should ask the answer if possible

Comment: Ultimately, if the interview question was worded exactly as you describe then it was a bad question.  What does "do partial classes" mean?  Most of the observed functionality of partial classes can be similarly achieved through other means, but those other means are not partial classes.  To create an *actual* partial class, you need to use the `partial` keyword.

Comment: I like @YuliamChandra comment.  I like interviews where I learn something.  Asking questions back and interacting is part of that.  But that might be better suited to [workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You can always make your own text parser that combines .cs files and then use the Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider class to compile.

Comment: I think this was a poor question trying to get extension methods mentioned.  I've been interviewed by the clueless enough times to get that feeling.

Comment: Parhaps they were testing you, whether you'd make up an answer if you didn't know the correct answer (or in case there was *no* answer at all)

Answer (score 2):

I think - use Extensions

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public Method1()
    {
    }
}

public static class MyClassExt
{
    public static Method2(this MyClass myClass)
    {
    }
}

MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.Method1();
mc.Method2();
```

Comment: And you can't access private methods nor add ctor, properties, fields, static methods, private methods, virtuals,...

Comment: For some observed functionality this may appear similar, but this definitely does not replicate what a partial class is.

Comment: But using extensions, you have no access to some fields...

Comment: Yes it`s not full functionality as partial.

Answer (score 0):

Write a small script that before compilation "concatenates" the different files.

Such script could look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -P $2 "using .*" > $3
tac $1 | sed '0,/}/{s/}//}' | tac >> $3
grep -v -P ".*class.* {" < $2 >> $3
```

And then call it with `script File1.cs File2.cs ResultingFile.cs` (If you want to support namespaces, more advanced techniques should be used). You can, for most IDE's specify scripts that should be executed before compilation.

---

Another possible way to do this is using subclassing. Say you have a partial class `Foo`:

**File1**

```
public partial class Foo {

    //methods part 1

}
```

**File2**

```
public partial class Foo {

    //methods part 2

}
```

To:

```
public abstract class FooBase {

    //methods part 1

}
```

and:

```
public class RealFoo : FooBase {

    //methods part 2

}
```

All fields should then be made public and you should define abstract signatures for the methods of part 2 so that you can call them.

Comment: @CommuSoft In which language is this script?

Comment: As you can see on the first line: `bash` (or `/bin/bash`, the shebang for Linux)